# Mirror iPad 2 screen on Mac

Tags: ipad, mac, display

I would like to know if there is a possibility to display the iPad 2 screen on my Mac?
You know, silmilar to the Steve Jobs presentations.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not on your Mac, but you can use and HDMI or VGA cable to a separate monitor that will then mirror the iPad2 display.

Answer (score 2):

[Reflector](http://www.reflectorapp.com/) should fulfill your needs.

> AirPlay mirror your iPhone 4S, iPad 2 or iPad 3 to any Mac running OS X 10.6+, wirelessly.

[image: Reflector]
Reflector is a paid app ($14.99 for each computer), with a trial.

Comment: Per their website: "AirPlay mirror your iPhone 4S, iPad 2 or iPad 3 to any Mac running OS X 10.6+, wirelessly."

A trial is also available before you make the purchase, so you can determine how well it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a Mac app that can receive AirPlay streams you should be able to use AirPlay mirroring, the same way you would for an apple TV.

AirPlayer http://ericasadun.com/ftp/Macintosh/ is one example of this but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com/?p=1397) ($14.99) which will allow you to do exactly what you need and much more (streaming of all kinds of content including music, movies, photos, YouTube,...)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If your device is jailbroken, then you can use apps like Veency to mirror. Actually there are lot of apps available in cydia.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a [composite cable from Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC748ZM/A?fnode=MTY1NDAzOQ&mco=MTM3NTMzMTM) to get the input to your monitor. You might need a converter from composite to draw input.

You would need a HDMI slot to use your Mac as input AFAIK